# Novel; gender determined at puberty

Tags: story-identification, novel

A world where the natives are born gender neutral; at puberty they develop into male or female.

The main character believes that her body made the wrong choice.

I think it was written in the early 80's, but I am fuzzy on that.

Not "Halfway Human" by Carolyn Ives Gilman.

Not "The Left Hand of Darkness".

Comment: Can you remember anything about the cover? Or any other details?

Comment: Ahh. I found it.  David Gerrold, "Moonstar Odyssey"

Comment: :) Then post it as an answer with what details match.

Comment: Anyone interested in this question might enjoy James Alan Gardner's novel, [Commitment Hour ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_Hour): "*Set on post-apocalyptic Earth, Tober Cove most resembles a rural, seventeenth century fishing village, with one exception: every year, everyone below the age of 21 changes gender. At the age of twenty-one, the people of the village must "commit" to being male, female or both in the form of a Hermaphrodite (a 'Neut'), forever. Commitment Hour follows the day leading up to the main character's hour of commitment.*"

Answer (score 6):

Because I feel uneasy when the answer hasn't been posted... user1538392, feel free to to cannibalize my answer for your own.

The querent has identified this as David Gerrold's *[Moonstar Odyssey](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/991414.Moonstar_Odyssey)*.

[image: Front cover of *Moonstar Odyssey*]

> SHE WAS BORN IN THE MOON'S SHADOW
>   ...when the storms of Satlik raged their worst. Because of this Jobe was different. The family never spoke of it but everyone knew Jobe was special. So Jobe came to know of it too. She had a destiny beyond that of Choice, beyond that moment when she must finally decide for Reethe, Mother of the World, or for Dakka, Father, Son, and Lover. For others it was easy, but not for her, not for Jobe. So she was sent to Option, the island of learning, to make her choice and become who she must be. And slowly, ever so slowly, Jobe retreated from the world, from the time of decision. Then the ultimate cataclysm wracked the planet, threatening all her people had struggled so hard to create, and Jobe came forth at last to fulfill her destiny and begin the quest that the moonstar had set for her so many years ago....

Comment: I thought exactly this when I read the question title.  +1